# Failing to Record using opencv 2.2 and Python 2.7

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, video-recording

I am trying to write a code to record video from webcam using opencv 2.2 and python 2.7. I got a code which seem to give me an error.

Code:

```
import cv, sys

cap = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)   # 0 is for /dev/video0
if not cap:
    sys.stdout.write("!!! Failed CaptureFromCAM")
    sys.exit(1)

frame = cv.RetrieveFrame(cap)
if not frame: 
    sys.stdout.write("!!! Failed to retrieve first frame")
    sys.exit(1)


fps = 25.0      # so we need to hardcode the FPS
print "Recording at: ", fps, " fps"  

frame_size = cv.GetSize(frame)
print "Video size: ", frame_size  

writer = cv.CreateVideoWriter("out.mp4", cv.CV_FOURCC('F', 'M', 'P', '4'), 
                              fps, frame_size, True)
if not writer:
    sys.stdout.write("!!! Error in creating video writer")
    sys.exit(1)


while True :
    if not cv.GrabFrame(cap) : 
        break
    frame = cv.RetrieveFrame(cap)
    cv.WriteFrame(writer, frame)

cv.ReleaseVideoWriter(writer)
cv.ReleaseCapture(cap)
```

Error is:

```
!!! Failed to retrieve first frame Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\WORKING PROGRAMS\mp4.py", line 11, in
<module>
    sys.exit(1) SystemExit: 1
```

I often get error such as [this (image)](http://i47.tinypic.com/2cndrux.png)on my Windows 7 machine when I try to run python programs without any error.